# Why is GetAccessControl function very slow at first time?

Tags: c#, performance, file-permissions

I am checking if I can access a share folder or not.

This is my code:

```
var readAllow = false;
var readDeny = false;
var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
if (accessControlList == null)
    return false;
var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
if (accessRules == null)
    return false;

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
{
    if ((FileSystemRights.Read & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Read) continue;

    if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
        readAllow = true;
    else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
        readDeny = true;
}

return readAllow && !readDeny;
```

My problem is that first time after I restart the PC, `Directory.GetAccessControl(path)` takes about 8s.

But if I execute it again, it is very fast (<1s).

Why is `GetAccessControl` function very slow at first time?

How can fix this problem?

Comment: Related: [Setting ACE slow for folder with many files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10174585/7444103). -- [How do we change permissions on a share as fast as Explorer does it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151007-00/?p=91421)